# What is the Big O notation for .sizeOf(type) opperation in C#?

Tags: c#, big-o, sizeof, notation

This is the piece of code im looking at. It is meant to show the size of my data structure. What I need to know is the Big O of this, I have looked everywhere and no luck. I'm not so sure how to calculate it myself. Any help is apricated!

```
  int size = System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(Point));
        Console.WriteLine(size);
```

Comment: `O(1)`, it's strictly a metadata operation AFAIK

Comment: Big O deals with how much more work an algorithm does as the data set increases. `SizeOf` takes one input. There's no possibility of data set increase, so O(1) is the only possibility.

Comment: @madreflection Technically speaking, we don't know if `SizeOf` iterates over each field every time you call it, so it could potentially be `O(fieldCount)`, I suspect not though

Comment: @madreflection Indeed, as I thought, [`MethodTable::GetNativeLayoutInfo()`](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/1ee59da9f6104c611b137c9d14add04becefdf14/src/coreclr/vm/methodtable.cpp#L9440) only initializes once. Quite deep in the call tree, but interesting anyway

Comment: I think the question is not what time complexity of SizeOf is, its why you need to know this information, and what you think the benefit is, because based on a few assumptions this question becomes an xy problem fast